# Revolutionary is to revolution as reactionary is to _____

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to think of a noun meaning "the process sought to be undertaken by one who is reactionary."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word you're looking for is [reaction](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/reaction).

Comment: Also include the definition given at the source, and any usage examples you could. That makes it a proper 'answer'.